# Guaranteed delivery on Google Cloud Messaging API

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have a little doubt about the GCM API service, I'm currently using the free version of Google Cloud and have been using the GCM API for about a month and from my perspective the noficiations sent with the API are delivered half of the time, I'm not sure if I'm using it the wrong way or if all my messages are being throttled as there's no way to track the messages sent with this API.
In case anyone wonders I'm using GCM with a PHP server with the following parameters:

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
        'time_to_live' => 0,
        'priority'=>'high'            
    );
```

I have also tried to take out the TTL and priority to check if the message deliver in any way but it didn't work.

My question about this is, if I buy the Cloud service, does it have any guarantee about the delivery of messages sent with the GCM API? or it's the same service?

Comment: What client are you using to receive the messages?

Comment: What do you mean by client? The device or the class that receives the message?

Comment: The devices that are receiving the messages

Comment: A real device, I tried with the Android Studio emulator but since it doesn't have google services it wouldn't work. I'm actually running it on a LG 970h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [this document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/), GCM is completely free and no paid version exists.

> The GCM service handles all aspects of queueing of messages and
>   delivery to client applications running on target devices, and it is
>   completely free.

Please note that if you set your TTL to 0, it means:'now or never'. So if there is any issue with your Wifi or Data Network, no retry happens.

However if you have this issue with GCM (50% delivery rate), it should be something wrong with your implementation, otherwise you can open a ticket on [GCM support page](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support)